# R append data to df columns by grep search (each pattern = new column)

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

There is a list of patterns and a list of words.
I need to create a data frame with columns as patterns and append matches into it.
Let's say patterns are:

patterns <- c("arm", "end", "tale")

And the word list is:

words <- c("arm", "end", "fairytale", "armchair", "deadend", "farm")

df should look like this:

| arm | end | tale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| arm | end | fairytale |
| armchair | deadend |  |
| farm |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
x <- lapply(setNames(patterns, patterns), grep, words, value = TRUE)
as.data.frame(lapply(x, `length<-`, max(lengths(x))))
#       arm     end      tale
#1      arm     end fairytale
#2 armchair deadend      <NA>
#3     farm    <NA>      <NA
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `rowr` and `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(rowr)
map(patterns,
      ~ str_subset(words, .x)) %>%
       invoke(cbind.fill, ., fill = NA) %>%
       setNames(patterns)
```

-output

```
     arm     end      tale
1      arm     end fairytale
2 armchair deadend      <NA>
3     farm    <NA>      <NA>
```